# Fetch youtube video line from freebase result id

Tags: youtube-api, freebase

I need to fetch the video link to show trailer of a movie  which I am searching using freebase API. SO is it possible to fetch the link using freebase result mid/id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a freebase topic related video search on youtube via [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) call.

Set the [part](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#part) = "snippet" [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) = "video" and [topicId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#topicId) = "YOUR_TOPIC_ID"

Comment: Thanks, I will implement it asap and will let you know